# How to change the application insights cloud role name for an azure function in python?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, opencensus

Basically as said in title.

I've read doc on callback functions and changes of variables but where does this all go?

I suspect I'm missing something but im not sure what

What needs to exist for this change to happen?

I suspect its something to do with OpenCensus,handlers and loggers but im not entirely confident what their functions are.

my function is written in vscode and the code is written entirely in Python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set the cloud role name for Application Insights in an Azure Function App by using the **WEBSITE_CLOUD_ROLENAME** environment variable. This will allow you to segregate logs and understand that they are coming from different apps.

https://sergeykibish.com/blog/how-to-set-app-insights-cloud-role-name-for-azure-functions/